# How to force Discord to send a link without an embed?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send a message containing a link through a Discord bot (something like: *for more information click on the following link*).

The problem is that everytime that I send it, Discord generetes an Embed for that message, which in a normal case would be nice, except i don't want it, as it looks very spammy.

I have tried stopping the embed with that `embed=None`, but it doesn't do it's job.

```py
msg = await channel.send("Click on this link: https://somewhere.com", embed=None)
```

Acording to [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.Empty), i should use `embed=discord.Embed.Empty`, but it is throwing me an error inside the lib files.

Any ideas? Maybe i could edit the message after sending it and try to remove the embed, but i don't think it will work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put the link between `<>`

```py
msg = await channel.send("Click on this link: <https://somewhere.com>")
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast and easy. Don't know how I missed that out... thanks!